# emit/ send/ retrieve data from uncompleted workflow activity in workflow foundation

Tags: c#, events, persistence, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

In a workflow application, when the workflow is pausing and waiting for inputs, I can't find a way to send the data results of the current activity bookmark to the client.
Can anyone help?

```
wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(wf, inputs);

        wfApp.Completed = (e) =>
        {

            int Turns = Convert.ToInt32(e.Outputs["Turns"]);

        };
```

something like:

```
       wfApp.Paused= (e) => 
        {

            WFReturnActivityData dataToSendToClient = e.Outputs["DataToSendToClient "];
            return dataToSendToClient 

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use extensions to do just that. Basically you register a custom class that is used to communicate with the host. That class can expose methods that outputs data, for example write data to the Console.

See http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1091/workflow-foundation-40-extension for an introduction.

Comment: However it is not exactly what I am looking for. I need the workflow to communicate with the host before getting completed. maybe a custom event or something. When the workflow is not completed and "waiting" for user action, display the data from activity or extension

Comment: Well, you can create a custom activity that uses the extension to output data, and put that in your workflow just before the waiting for user interaction activity. Can you tell a bit more about the activities involved in the waiting for user action scenario?

Comment: between two state, the activity must ask the user to choose between many propositions. depending on the answer, it will brings him to one or another state.

Comment: Ok, then using Bookmarks seem like a good fit. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489442(v=vs.100).aspx and http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1016/workflow-foundation-40-bookmark. Hmm you already thought of that I see. Can you tell a bit more about the workflow itself, how dit you implement the current bookmarks in your workflow?